# Taking an intro Flash/AS3 course; problems with MVC pattern

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, model-view-controller, oop

Okay, so I've been busting my hump the last week or so on this project for my OOP/AS3 course and this past Sunday I realized that my approach wasn't going to work so I scrapped the better part of it and started over.

Our assignment is to create an XML based flash menu that demonstrates an understanding of the OOP patterns we've just learned.  It was kind of a 'test the waters' project where he gave us a ton of tutorials and information and told us to make our best attempt at making sense of it so I'm certain there are more efficient ways to do what I'm doing, but that's a moot point.

We need to employ at least two patterns in our menu, though at the moment I'm just focusing on MVC so that I can get the mainUI working before I finalize the second part of the UI.  It essentially flows like so:

- MainUI has 4 menus that slide out.
- Each slider has 3 thumbnails on it.
- Clicking on any of the thumbnails will move to the next part of the UI. This functionality is currently disabled.

The program runs with 0 compiler errors, but the images are not being placed on the stage correctly and I can't figure out why. All the image paths are being pulled and stored from the XML properly. The main background image is pulled once and is supposed to be only placed once (if statement that uses a count to determine whether to run the placement function or not), but it is being placed 4 times with the sliding menu image.  The sliders are being placed in the correct positions (switch statement that iterates through the mainUI function in the View class and creates a separate loader for each one), but the thumbnails are not all showing up. So here is what I'm seeking help with:

- The mainPanel image should only be placed once, rather than 4 times with each slider.
- The sliders, while being placed correctly, must be tweened in different directions through the as (using TweenMax), but each instance is unidentifiable from the other so right now they all have an eventListener that calls the same tween method.  How can I distinguish them in a way that lets me apply a different tween to each (This will likely be a concern with the thumbnail functionality later as I will need to load different XML data based on which thumb is clicked).

I have added what I hope are very informative comments to each script so hopefully people can help. Also included are images of what I want the mainUI to eventually look like and how it's coming out currently.

- pastebin with all 3 classes and XML (2 hyperlink limit) - http://pastebin.com/u/crookedparadigm
- top image is how the stage is outputting, bottom image is what I'd like to to be - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChPOP.jpg

Last quick note, stage is currently set to 600x480 with a black background.  Ideally, to reinforce OOP principles, our professor wants us to avoid using the timeline or library if possible.

Any advice at all will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install [FlexPMD](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexpmd/FlexPMD) This is a very good add on( sometimes hard to install ) It basically is used to show areas of your code that you are not following standards. For example your classes lack the use of "this". And you should avoid passing parameters in constructors. It would be good practice to develop standardized writing skills while you are still new.

Looking at your code I see you are calling `buildUI` from within a loop.
`buildUI` is assigning a `MainView` object to `mainUI`.
So each time you go through a loop iteration you are reassigning mainUI.
In the end `mainUI` will only be the last iteration of that loop.
Not sure this is your issue but is an issue.



[EDIT]
Excellent Singleton guide for Flex SDK
[Part 1](http://blog.skinkers.com/2010/03/01/using-the-flex-singleton-register-pt-13/)
[Part 2](http://blog.skinkers.com/2010/03/08/using-the-flex-singleton-register-pt-23-overriding-flex-implementations/)


[Some Good writing on pure AS3 Singletons.](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html)

Comment: Hmm, I think I understand. Please correct me if I've got this wrong, but since loop ends up calling buildUI (and subsequently, the menuView class) wouldn't it run through the menuView function before completing the next iteration of the loop? Something like this maybe:


Loop > if > call to buildUI > buildUI substantiates mainUI as an instance of the menuView class, passing parameters pulled from the above function > menuView class' constructor runs using XML data from the loop > switch() in buildUI places the loaded elements on the stage based on the loop's iteration > the loop runs again

Comment: Please tell me if that's not the correct sequence of events.  I'll also take a look at the addon you recommended.

Comment: inside a loop using the "new" will create a new instance of an object and detatch the reference to the object that it was so you would have 2 objects, however, in a function I am not sure how it will be handled, Probably the same way. Either way you are still only keeping a reference to the last iteration. Personally I would create a Menu class that will be a Singleton( for one of your patterns ). And let the Menu class load instances of custom class loader that will handle your images. The keyword with this would be encapsulation.

Comment: In my example I would have a mainUI array that would hold this references as I add them to stage. Also I added some links for you in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I think I'm on my way to both fixing my code up and getting things working properly.

Comment: Using singletons is definitely not best practice OOP. Please don't encourage people to use them.

Answer (score -1):

I would prolly start from scratch as your XML data is miss formatted.

your XML should resemble something like this.

```
<MainProject>
<MainUI>
    <Thumbnail Name="Spring">
        <Destination Name="Spring" Price="99" ratingPath="images/SP1/SP1rating.png" />
    </Thumbnail>

    <Thumbnail Name="Winter">
        <Destination Name="Winter" Price="152" ratingPath="images/SP1/SP2rating.png" />
    </Thumbnail>
</MainUI>
</MainProject>
```

Then you should have the following structure on your stage. These movieclips should be empty and already placed inside on your stage with instance name.

```
Stage
    MenuUI MovieClip
        ThumbNail1 MovieClip <- feed it thumbnail from the XML
        ThumbNail2 MovieClip <- feed it thumbnail from the XML
        ThumbNail3 MovieClip <- feed it thumbnail from the XML
        ThumbNail4 MovieClip <- feed it thumbnail from the XML
```

This might be a bit too vague, just tell me if you need more details.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Of course theirs nothing wrong with your XML except the fact that its mapping properties as objects and vice-verse. down voting the only help you get.

Comment: I didn't down vote anything...I can't even if I wanted to, I'm too new.

I am attempting to do this without using the timeline, library, or placing any movieclips directly on the stage.  It's all supposed to be done through AS.  I'm also pretty new to AS and OOP so I'm sorry if I don't understand the extra utility of your suggestion, but I'm thankful for any help!

Comment: @Dr.Denis McCracleJizz I beg to differ. I down voted because the answer is just plain wrong. The only thing I might do different in the XML is use some node attributes. But in this case there is nothing wrong and plus he stated he wasn't having problems reading the XML.

Comment: I never stated anywhere that the reading was the problem. The problem is OBVIOUSLY the miss representation of the data between the controller and the model. One might think that reorganizing the model would be a beneficial action. Also i understand that you are trying to only work with Actionscript but formatting your workspace structure with MovieClips inside flash is a powerful work tool, use it.

Comment: @Dr.Denis McCracleJizz That part is not up to me, he is taking that into consideration for the grading so I'm trying to stick to pure AS. Thank you for your suggestions though.

Comment: @Denis Then why are you stating "your XML data is miss formatted." And you should never use MovieClips in a pure AS project unless you need frame support Which the OP stated here that he does not want frame support. If anything at the least use Sprite.

Comment: What ever inherites from displayobjectcontainer.